# how to configure Multiple Tomcat instance with seperate JVM in windows

Tags: apache, tomcat, jvm, geoserver, httpserver

I have installed and configured 6 instance of Apache Tomcat in windows, and i put 6 copy of Geoserver webapps in all that instance.Using Apache HTTP Server i also done load balancing  to increase request handling speed but still the request rendering is very slow.

I figured that configuring each tomcat to working in a separate JVM will increase speed.

Is that possible ?

please give me some suggestion to increase the performance

really am struck here please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
without additional information on what you are trying to do (data format, data size, what applications are accessing geoserver, etc. etc..) it is impossible to answer.

A good starting point to optimize performance, which usually involves preprocessing your data is this presentation:

http://goo.gl/74XUPq

Simone.